# Is it acceptable practice in Java to nest try/catch statements?

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

I am trying to create an IP address in Android from a passed in value (using Bundle), and if it fails I'm creating it using a default IP address that is hard coded.  If that fails then I am exiting the app.

What I'd like to know is if its ok to nest try/catch's as I have done here, or is there a better way.

```
try {
    // serverSettings is the Bundle name that was passed in.
    ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverSettings.getString("serverIp"));
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Failed to create IP, trying default");
    try {
        // DEFAULT_IP is the hard-coded default fall-back address
        ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_IP);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Total fail, exiting");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have written it exactly like this including the comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's legal Java. It looks clunky to me, and I'd probably do it differently, but it's valid and works.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
public InetAddress getServerAddress() {
    for (String address : new String[] {serverSettings.getString("serverIp"), DEFAULT_IP}) {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getByName(address);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR:", "Cannot resolve " + address);
        }
    }
    Log.e("ERROR:", "Total fail, exiting");
    finish();
    return null;    // not reached
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, this looks like a nice tidy way to do it, and would probably be a far better way if I ever got into more layers of nesting.  Cheers, Steve

Answer (score 4):

I think it's going to be debatable what way is better, but here's another option that some may consider to be a bit more "expressive" and readable, though it's more lines of code:

```
public InetAddress tryHost(String hostName) {
    InetAddress address = null;
    try {
        address = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in your code, just do:

```
InetAddress address = null;
address = tryHost(serverSettings.getString("serverIp"));
if (address = null)
    address = tryHost(DEFAULT_IP);
if (address = null) {
    // handle error, throw exception
}
finish();
```

Comment: Agree, it's quite debatable. But I really like all the proposed options.

Comment: I like this way too, but I think Chris' option looks tidier overall.  Its good to know there are a pile of different acceptable ways to do this tho

Answer (score 2):

Another variation is to set the default first:

```
ipAddress = null;
try {
    // serverSettings is the Bundle name that was passed in.
    ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_IP); // Set default address
    ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverSettings.getString("serverIp")); // Try passed-in address
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    if (ipAddress == null) {
        Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Total fail, exiting");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

If the call using the Bundle'd value fails, then the exception is thrown before ipAddress is modified, so ipAddress is already set to the default. Of course, this is only a valid pattern if DEFAULT_IP should always be resolvable.

Comment: Thats a nice simple option - but unfortunately the DEFAULT_IP will probably not be resolvable... its more there for testing in my environment (where it will resolve), but in the real world it probably won't.  Cheers, Steve

Answer (score 1):

It's OK. You could also use a boolean flag which gets turned on in the 1st catch, so you execute the request by IP outside the catch, if your boolean flag is turned on.

```
boolean failed = false;
try {
    // serverSettings is the Bundle name that was passed in.
    ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverSettings.getString("serverIp"));
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    failed = true;
    Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Failed to create IP, trying default");    
}

if(failed){
    try {
            // DEFAULT_IP is the hard-coded default fall-back address
            ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_IP);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Total fail, exiting");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this.  It's a bit cleaner and doesn't involve extra flags.

```
InetAddress ipAddress = null;
try {
    // serverSettings is the Bundle name that was passed in.
    ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverSettings.getString("serverIp"));
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Failed to create IP, trying default");
}
if(ipAddress==null){
    try {
        // DEFAULT_IP is the hard-coded default fall-back address
        ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_IP);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Total fail, exiting");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: surely if you're in the catch statement then we know that the address == null?  So adding the 'if' is just extra unnecessary code?  I think the nesting idea is probably tidier - I was just concerned about the acceptability of it more than anything... Cheers, Steve

Comment: Yes, they both work well but most people find it more readable to avoid nested exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variation I like when working through a larger set of tests (on a first-wins basis):

```
ipAddress = null;
// serverSettings is the Bundle name that was passed in.
String[] addresses = { DEFAULT_IP,
                       serverSettings.getString("serverIp") };

int i = 0;
do {
    try {
        ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(addresses[i]);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Failed to create IP, trying next");
    }
} while (ipAddress == null && i < addresses.length);

if (ipAddress == null) {
    Log.e("ERROR:", "IOException: Total fail, exiting");
    e1.printStackTrace();
    finish();
}
```

This is probably more appropriate in my normal use case (looping through SimpleDateFormats to match 3rd-party date strings)